# Finding Multiple Integers Inside A String Using Regex

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I currently have this code below:

```
    Pattern intsOnly = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher matcher = intsOnly.matcher(o1.getIngredients());
    matcher.find();
    String inputInt = matcher.group();
```

What currently happens is that using Regex, it finds the first integer inside a string and separates it so that I can carry out actions on it. The string that I am using to find integers inside of has many integers and I want them all separate. How can I tweak this code so that it also records the other integers from the string, not just the first one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your string data look like and are you using Java platform?

Comment: It's a set of ingredients. An example would be like this: 1 egg, 2 bacon rashers, 3 potatoes. I need to find all three of those numbers, in that example. Currently I'm only pulling back the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your posted code:

```
matcher.find();
String inputInt = matcher.group();
```

You are matching the whole string with a single call to find. And then assigning the first match of digits to your String `inputInt`. So for example, if you have the below string data, your return will only be `1`.

```
1 egg, 2 bacon rashers, 3 potatoes
```

You should use a `while` loop to loop over your matches.

```
Pattern intsOnly = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher = intsOnly.matcher(o1.getIngredients());
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much man. It works perfectly and reads out all the relevant numbers. I'm new to Regex and wasn't really thinking straight. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Now that I've found the integers, I want to multiply them by a value and then place them back in the original string with the new multiplied number. Can you help me to achieve this? How should I tackle that?

Comment: Thought I'd post a new question so that you'd get the chance to earn more Reputation. Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971006/multiply-integers-inside-a-string-by-an-individual-value-using-regex